# Config::LoadFile: Failed open file 'configs/authserver.conf.dist'

Tags: azerothcore

When trying to open the `authserver` or the `worldserver` I get the error

> Config::LoadFile: Failed open file 'configs/authserver.conf.dist'

The configs folder is populated with the `authserver.conf`, `authserver.conf.dist`, `worldserver.conf`, `worldserver.conf.dist` and I am able to edit them.

Here the path of the authserver and the path of the `.dist`

`C:\\Build\\bin\\RelWithDebInfo\\authserver.exe`

`C:\\Build\\bin\\RelWithDebInfo\\configs\\authserver.conf.dist`

I have tried rebuilding AzerothCore.sln a few times using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 but get the same error when I get to the Step 4 in the installation guide and try to open the apps.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `RelWithDebInfo` as an exception to your security software. If that doesn't work run the auth and world server as an admin.
Usually, when you get a failed open file error, it's usually the wrong directory or permissions.