# Config::LoadFile: Failed to open file 'configs/authserver.conf worldserver.conf'

Tags: azerothcore

Authserver and Worldserver wont start. 'Failed open file'

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yhx4.png)

My 'configs' folder looks like this:
[configs folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsrAN.png)

'RelWithDebInfo' looks like this:
[RelWithDebInfo folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mUoa.png)

All the config/dist files have the same database info.

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74282774/configloadfile-failed-open-file-configs-authserver-conf-dist).

I added the folder to exceptions, and ran the .exe's as admin. Same error.

I've tried rebuilding.

Comment: I figured it out. I just named the files .conf and didn't actually save them as a .conf file. It's all working now after I realized and fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in your conf folder screenshot, you do not have .conf files, you have .dist files and (probably) .txt files.

Enable the display of the file extension in your (windows?-)settings to be able to change them.